# Intentional Inexistence?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, intentionality

Intentionality is known as the directedness or 'aboutness' of our perceiving, believing, desiring, etc.

Yet, there is something peculiar that the object of intentional attitudes need not be real. For example, I may believe in unicorns while they are not real.

Therefore, many philosophers claim that intentional relations are not real, unlike other relations such as 'x is smaller than y' in which x and y are real objects.

However, it also makes sense that I can believe in the existence of real things or real state of affairs.

Is there a way to salvage intentionality ontologically, and also explain how it can be direcred towards an inexistent object?

Comment: since at least the middle ages, one solution is to understand an intentional relation as a modal modification of the self in which case this would be an intentional relationship between the self and a concept (whether in the head of the person having it or understood to reach a shared social object)...

Comment: You can see this detailed discussion about [Intentionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/) and specifically the part about [the existence of intentional objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/#7).

Comment: Related: F.Berto, [Existence as a Real Property: The Ontology of Meinongianism](https://books.google.it/books?id=UobUqRMyUawC&pg=PR19) (2012).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "salvage intentionality ontologically"? Any interpretation would have to distinguish between relations to real and fictional objects, like Pegasus. Are you asking for ontology that postulates fictional objects as external "things" of some sort rather than mental or linguistic artifacts?

Comment: I want to say that even if intentional objects may not be real, intentionality itself is real.

Comment: Sounds like the Hinayama (Teravedic) school of Buddhism. Both the Mahayana school of Buddhism and the Advaita school of Vedanta have given numerous arguments against this. The argument is specious.

Answer (score 1):

There is a familiar way to "salvage" intentionality of non-existing objects, as a real (metaphysical) relation. But first, let's briefly describe the core problem. Metaphysics is supposed to describe reality as it is. And reality is supposed to consist of *existing* things, and just of them. Real properties are supposed then to exemplify existing things. Real relations are supposed to relate existing things. It therefore seems nonsensical to speak of a having a real relation with a non-existing thing. A thing that does not exist, if this even makes sense, is *ipso facto* not a part of reality, and so is not a part of the "web of existence" that metaphysics is due to describe.

If a real relation must have existing terms, why don't we make the desired term exist? And indeed, the familiar move is to hold that even non-existing objects exist ... in some mode. This requires, then, to distinguish several modes of existence. During the middle ages was developed the idea of a kind of intra-mental existence, alongside real extra-mental existence. This idea still figures in Descartes's proofs in the *Meditations*, where he distinguishes "objective" (mental) existence from "formal" (extra-mental) existence.

A more recent variation, which was motivated by Brentano's theory of intentionality, was Meinung's [theory of objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meinong/#ObjTheOntBeyBeiNonBei). His idea was to posit an ontological category of "objects", which is antecedent to existence, and which expresess the mere potential to be "intended" by a mind. So unlike the medieval idea of intra-mental objects, we now have a category of objects which are extra-mental (not internal to the mind, but intended by it) but might not (really) exist. If we also believe that being an object, in the renewed extra-mental sense of the word, is a sufficient condition for being a term of a real relation, we can allow relations with non-existing terms.

Meinung's approach is often believed to have been dealt a severe blow by Bertrand Russell's [theory of descriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_descriptions). The latter provided an alternative framework to explain how we seem to be able to intend non-existing objects.